Looking for identification on these 2 connectors (4 position, 1 row, 3.96mm pitch)
I'm looking for makes of these 2 4-position wire-to-wire power connectors.  I got them from XForce as part of their Varex valved exhaust kit, and I want to make some y-splitter pigtails.  The company can't tell me where they sourced the connectors.
Male connector (the small one, ignore the big one attached to the switch) https://xforceusa.com/products/vk05/
Pics: https://imgur.com/a/OYhTBOx
I'm looking for wire-to-wire straight through connectors. So far my searching on digikey and mouser has turned up nothing that looks like it would fit.

Please embed the pictures

My Identiconn utinility identifies that as a JST HV.

Female plug housing: JST VHR-4N
Male PCB header: B4P-VH

By the way, that PCB header is being abused as a male plug. That abuse makes that connection unreliable. That particular class of connectors doesn't offer a male plug because it is only wire-to-board, not wire-to-wire. The proper way to solve the problem is to install the male PCB header on a PCB and then solder wires to the PCB.

thanks for the note on that, this is the way it comes from xforce, but I might redo some stuff. Note that this will all be interior car-mounted, and once mounted, will likely not be touched again.

Thanks for how fast you found these, I'll bookmark that utility! I really appreciate it!
